# How to load parquet file using the $read_dictionary method?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I need to read a 7.5 mb parquet file containing 5 million rows and 11 columns, but this uses up more than 14 gb of memory on my system, which is unacceptable. Some research told me that I can tell arrow to read a column as a dictionary to speed up the process, as the main column has only a handful of unique values that divide up the dataset.

The `props` argument of `arrow::read_parquet` says there is a `⁠$read_dictionary(column_index)⁠` method that allows Arrow to interpret a column as a dictionary, thus lowering memory footprint. But I don't know how to set that argument, and the help documentation is very vague and has no examples, just giving a link to the [`ParquetArrowReaderProperties` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arrow/versions/8.0.0/topics/ParquetArrowReaderProperties) which is even vaguer.